# what is the default shortcut button is for VSCode's "Go forward" on the Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have the following keyboard shortcut for VSCode on my Mac by default as shown below, but I don't know what button it is.
What button is it?

command id : workbench.action.navigateForward

command title : Go forward

[image]

Comment: It's a control button on mac (`^`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I know it is the control key, but what is the button to the right of it?

Comment: it is the underscore (`_`), on US keyboard `Shift+minus` So it is `Ctrl+minus` (Go Back) and `Ctrl+Shift+minus` (Go Forward), I learned a new command/keybinding on VSC

Comment: When I press [shift + -] I get the =, does that mean my Mac is not a US keyboard?